# Simple mate in 2?

Tags: problems

I used to be a problem composer and the thing I loved most about creating and solving chess problems is that you can't just rely on simple patterns. You need to think outside the box. This is one of my earlier chess problems. Can you solve it?

#### White to move and mate in 2

```
[fen "3BB1N1/QKp3pb/7p/5R1R/3br1k1/7N/4P2P/6n1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adnan

```
1) Rf8 Ba7 2)Rh4#
```

or

```
1) Rf8 g5 2) Nh6#
```

Fun puzzle.

Comment: Why not `1. Rf1`?

Comment: Now I see, because `1... Bf2`.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Well done :)

Comment: These type of puzzles sometimes need a waiting move.

Comment: I first thought the solution was the ugly `1. Qxd4`, but then luckily black has `1... Nxh3`. I guess the value of a good problem is also in the alternative tries.

Comment: @AaronM It's actually not a waiting move. `1. Rf8` threatens `2. Rh4#` :).

Comment: Also 1.Rf8 Bf6 2.Qxd1#  and 1.Rf8 Bf2 2.Nxf2#

Comment: And also `1. Rf8 Re7 2. Rf4#`